# How to do with malloc instead of array of structure?

Tags: arrays, oracle, struct, malloc, proc

```
exec sql begin declare section;


struct factura {
long nis_rad;
long sec_nis;
long num_id_sipo;
char f_fact[9];
double imp_tot_rec;
}  *p;
```

if i do with array of structure(ex. struct factura x[100] instead *p all is ok

```
exec sql end declare section;
exec sql include sqlca;

void main (void) {

exec sql connect :user identified by :pass using :db_string;

if (sqlca.sqlcode==0)
{
printf("connect success");

p=(struct factura *)malloc(100*sizeof(struct factura));
exec sql declare c1 cursor for 
select nis_rad, sec_nis, num_id_sipo, f_fact, imp_tot_rec 
from recibos
where est_act = 'ER310';
exec sql open c1;
exec sql whenever not found do break;

 while(1)
{
    int i;

    exec sql fetch c1 into :p;

    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        (p+i)->num_id_sipo=1;

        printf("%d %d %d %s %f %d\n ", (p+i)->nis_rad, (p+i)->sec_nis,  (p+i)->num_id_sipo, (p+i)->f_fact, (p+i)->imp_tot_rec, count);
```

no compile error. it's something wrong with output. if i do with array of structure(ex. struct factura x[100] instead *p all is ok, but with malloc dont work.

Comment: give a question otherwise: How to fetch a multiply rows in a pointer like fetch a multimply rows in host array?